# Is it valid to list multiple fields in a single Vary header?

Tags: http, cache-control

I know you can do this

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Language
```

but can you do this

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

That's, btw, true for all header fields that can occur multiple times (with the exception of set-cookie, which has broken syntax). See [HTTP/1.1, part 1: URIs, Connections, and Message Parsing - Section 3.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-21#section-3.2).